# fetch hazelcast value by key

Tags: java, hazelcast

```
public class Model implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
```

Hazelcast Data-Storage

```
HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Model, String> hazelInstance = hazelCast.getMap("data");
hazelInstance.put(new Model("001","alia","23"), "john");
```

how to fetch value(John) by passing the any key..

Is that possible in hazelcast..?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fetch values by attributes of the map key, I think you should use IMap.values(Predicate) :

```
@Test
public void testFetchValue() {  
    IMap<Model, String> map = hazelcastTestClient.getMap("data");
    Model key = new Model("001","alia","23");
    map.put(key, "john");
    Model key2 = new Model("002","alia2","25");
    map.put(key2, "eric");
    Model key3 = new Model("003","alia3","23");
    map.put(key3, "peter");
    
    String value = map.get(key);
    Assert.assertTrue("value should be john", "john".equals(value));
    
    EntryObject eo = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
    Predicate idPredicate = eo.key().get("id").equal("001");
    Collection<String> valuesForName = map.values(idPredicate);
    Assert.assertTrue("values should contain john", valuesForName.contains("john"));
    Assert.assertFalse("values should not contain peter", valuesForName.contains("peter"));
    Assert.assertFalse("values should not contain eric", valuesForName.contains("eric"));
    
    eo = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
    Predicate agePredicate = eo.key().get("age").equal("23");
    Collection<String> valuesForAge = map.values(agePredicate);
    Assert.assertTrue("values should contain john", valuesForAge.contains("john"));
    Assert.assertTrue("values should contain peter", valuesForAge.contains("peter"));
    Assert.assertFalse("values should not contain eric", valuesForAge.contains("eric"));
}
```